# ag-Grid Cell Rendering - Custom Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

After looking through the [ag-Grid Cell Rendering documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0) I don't see a way to add custom properties to the cell renderer via the `cellRenderFramework` argument. For example, I'd like to pass in a callback to my custom renderer that is called when the button is clicked.

```
class AddCellRenderer extends React.Component<ICellRendererParams, {}> {

  /**
   * Callback handle to pass data to on a click.
   */
  public static callback = (data: MyData): void => { return; };

  public constructor(params: ICellRendererParams) {
    super(params);
  }

  public render() {
    let className = 'pt-button pt-intent-success pt-icon-add';
    let text = 'Click to add';
    if (this.props.data.saved) {
      className = 'pt-button pt-intent-danger pt-icon-remove';
      text = 'Click to remove';
    }
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick} className={className}>{text}</button>
    );
  }

  private onClick = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
    AddCellRenderer.callback(this.props.data);
    this.setState({ ...this.state }); // Make React update the component.
  }
}
```

And I have another component that uses it like so

```
public render() {
  let saveCellRenderer = AddCellRenderer;
  saveCellRenderer.callback = this.onSelectData;
  const columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      headerName: 'Add to Available Data',
      cellRendererFramework: AddCellRenderer,
    },
    ...
  ];
  ...
  }
```

There must be another way to pass this callback as props other than a static public method which is ugly and will not work when multiple components use the renderer, how do I go about doing this with ag-Grid?

Comment: Ended up using higher-order components to help get around this.

Answer (score 34):

I know this is late. But have you tried `cellRendererParams` with `cellRenderer`?
You can set custom props for the custom cell component using it. Eg:

```
columnDef = [
    .......
    {
        .......
        cellRenderer: CustomCellComponent,
        cellRendererParams: {
            prop1: "this is prop1"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Just to add on, you can still use the existing params defined in CellRendererParams like `value` and `data`. Just need to at them in the prop definition.

Comment: Relevant docs [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#complementing-cell-renderer-params) and [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#react-props). Note that for a headerComponentFramework renderer, you'll need to pass [headerComponentParams](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#complementing-params) instead.

Comment: Once `cellRendererParams` are added, how can they be accessed within `CustomCellComponent `? Pls help.

Comment: @StangSpree it should be available in props (props.prop1) of CustomCellComponent.

Comment: @IshworTimilsina using this you exchange state changes for these props ?

Comment: Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: Is it possible to add the component's props here as, cellRendererParams: {
            prop1: this.props.something }

Comment: @JollyGood I don't see why not.

Comment: hey @IshworTimilsina , any idea on how to modify the prop passed? For example i pass prop1, then modify it with a button on main component, and how do I reflect this change on the cell renderer component ? Been stuck on this for a while

Comment: @Mich I would simply add the changing data into the rowData when possible. If there are control issues, I would invert any non-static or non-derived data flow, following the "lifted state" principle of React, by passing a callback as cellRendererParams.onProp1 or gridOptions.context.onProp1 to let the cellRenderer notify the parent component that something needs to be done.

Comment: @StangSpree None of these were helping me, but your question made me realise that I'm passing the props alright, I'm just not accessing them correctly. I had to go back and put a debugger and play around; both of these worked for me: `params.prop1`, or `params.getValue('prop1')`

Comment: how can you pass parent data If you want to send id from data or any other value from any other field? I want to pass id value of the dataRow to field name and name uses NameComponent. how can I use id in NameComponent?